# jQuery get element height on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the height of a div tag on window resizing but I get always the same height. The event resizing is triggered correctly.

```
var resizeNews = this.resizeNews = function() {
    $('.top-news__pillar').each(function (index){
            console.log($(this).outerHeight());
            if($(this).outerHeight() > maxHeightPillar)  maxHeightPillar = $(this).outerHeight(); 
        });
```

/*if I don't set the height below the height correctly change when resizing*/

```
     $('.top-news__pillar').each(function (index){
          $(this).outerHeight(maxHeightPillar);
        });
   }

    $(window).on('resize',resizeNews);
```

Comment: Well, usually elements change their width when window is resized... Why do you expect them change height?

Comment: is there any CSS `height` for `top-news__pillar`?

Comment: Above code is working fine for me, add proper code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: are you changing the height of element ?

Comment: I have updated, yes I change the height and this seems cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `.outerHeight()` instead of `.height()`

Comment: If `height` is not changing how `outerHeight` will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var bodyheight = $('.top-news__pillar').height();
            console.log(bodyheight);
        }).resize();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get always same height why because if you specify your `top-news__pillar` element height in fixed unit like `px` instead of responsive unit like `%.

Even if you resize also your element height will be same. If you mention the element height in `%` you can see the height change when you resize the window.